# Query about temporary objects

Tags: c++

In Exceptional C++, item 10, its talking about use of a temporary (if you have the book, top of page 35 "... namely, the copy of the returned temporary into the destination").

The code is

```
template<class T>
T Stack::<T>::Pop()
{
...
T result = ...
return result;
}

...


string s1(s.Pop());
```

I'm not quite clear on what temporary is being created where and why.

When you return an object by value from a function is a temporary always created? Why and what's its scope?
In this case s1 is being copy constructed, presumably from the temporary? Why can it not be constructed from the result object within the function?

TIA

------- EDIT ---------
I think I got confused because the book is using the term copy, and its using it with the meaning of an operation while I was thinking of it meaning duplicate.
Verr good clear book in general, but this particular paragraph perhaps isn't as clear as it could be.

Comment: And I'd ask- is it even *possible* that more than one temporary object of type T is created in this example?

Answer (score 2):

The unnamed return value of the function *is* the temporary.  It's created as a return value of the function, and then passed to the copy constructor of the `string`, and then promptly destroyed.

Comment: So T result is the temporary? I got it into my head it was talking about an additional unnamed temporary.

Comment: The temporary is the unnamed instance of `T` returned by `T Stack<T>::Pop()`

Answer (score 1):

The return value is the temporary being created. Some compilers implement something called [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) that avoids the extra copy construction.

Note that the `T result = ...` line also creates a copy in the original text.

Comment: `T variable = T_expression` never creates more temporaries than `T variable(T_expression)`. The difference in temporaries only comes into play when the type of the expression is not `T`.

Comment: True, but operator[] usually returns a reference, which means you're doing a copy when storing it into a value type.